# TexStudio for macOS internal browser (external pdf is okay) does not show Chinese text

Tags: texstudio, mac, ctex

The .pdf file generated is right.But view problem like this:
[image]

Comment: If your ordinary pdf viewer shows file as it should be, then texstudio has some problems. But I think the issue is that compiler didn't understand chinese script. It is better if you use XeLaTeX compiler, with some chinese font.

Comment: Check the system preferences in Mac OS X if the support for kanji is fully enabled. Maybe the problem lies there.